# C# get value from hidden input

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I've been trying to get the value from a hidden input and innertext from a span on a website (note that I don't have access to edit the HTML code).

Code from website:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidv" value="1582912961">
<span class="valo">0.888</span>
```

I could use a code similar to this but don't know the correct use of it:

```
    label5.Text = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("hidv").InnerText;
    label6.Text = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("valo").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'd put an ID on the input tag

```
<input id="myId" type="hidden" name="hidv" value="1582912961">
```

Then you could use JS, jQuery, etc, to select the value.

```
$('#myId').val();

$('input[name=hidv]').val()
```

also just a note `Document.GetElementById` requires an Id. Otherwise, you could've done `Document.GetElementsByClassName("valo")` if you wanted to use the class name instead of an Id attribute.

Comment: I dont have access ti change the html code on the webserver

Comment: alert($('input[name=zyx]').val()); or just $('input[name=zyx]').val();